# Meaning of the hs_gc profiler counters in JMH

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jmh

I'm using the JMH benchmarking tool with the hs_gc hotspot profiler.

The issue I'm having is that I am unsure what the output counter values mean and cannot find a reference on the net.

Would anyone be able to point me in the direction of a specification or explain these values?

I have pasted an example output below:

```
HS(GC) | difference: {

sun.gc.collector.0.invocations=16,
sun.gc.collector.0.lastEntryTime=37106821,
sun.gc.collector.0.lastExitTime=37109336,
sun.gc.collector.0.time=1528884,

sun.gc.collector.1.invocations=6,
sun.gc.collector.1.lastEntryTime=34419368,
sun.gc.collector.1.lastExitTime=35532892,
sun.gc.collector.1.time=6721387,

sun.gc.generation.0.space.0.used=872712984,
sun.gc.generation.1.space.0.used=5721334504,
sun.gc.generation.2.space.0.used=4848,

sun.gc.policy.avgBaseFootprint=5312,

sun.gc.policy.avgMajorIntervalTime=-667,
sun.gc.policy.avgMajorPauseTime=-41,

sun.gc.policy.avgMinorIntervalTime=-557,
sun.gc.policy.avgMinorPauseTime=1,

sun.gc.policy.avgOldLive=88064,
sun.gc.policy.avgPromotedAvg=421184,
sun.gc.policy.avgPromotedDev=364832,
sun.gc.policy.avgPromotedPaddedAvg=1515648,
sun.gc.policy.avgSurvivedAvg=1056640,
sun.gc.policy.avgSurvivedDev=-189440,
sun.gc.policy.avgSurvivedPaddedAvg=488320,
sun.gc.policy.avgYoungLive=2708352,

sun.gc.policy.liveAtLastFullGc=5721334504,
sun.gc.policy.liveSpace=2801664,

sun.gc.policy.majorGcCost=5,
sun.gc.policy.majorPauseYoungSlope=-3,

sun.gc.policy.minorGcCost=2,
sun.gc.policy.minorPauseTime=3,
sun.gc.policy.minorPauseYoungSlope=1,

sun.gc.policy.mutatorCost=-7,

sun.gc.policy.oldEdenSize=11534336,
sun.gc.policy.promoted=4584928,
sun.gc.policy.survived=6194624,

sun.gc.tlab.alloc=12852845,
sun.gc.tlab.fills=-15,

sun.gc.tlab.gcWaste=-100979,
sun.gc.tlab.maxFills=-22,
sun.gc.tlab.maxGcWaste=-100859,
sun.gc.tlab.maxSlowAlloc=-5,
sun.gc.tlab.maxSlowWaste=8826,

sun.gc.tlab.slowAlloc=-5,
sun.gc.tlab.slowWaste=8849}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [Serviceability in HotSpot: HotSpot Jvmstat Performance Counters](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/docs/Serviceability.html#bjvmstat) has the following warning about this:

> The counters have structured names such as `sun.gc.generation.1.name`, `java.threads.live`, `java.cls.loadedClasses`. The names of these counters and the data structures used to represent them are considered private, uncommitted interfaces to the HotSpot JVM. Users should not become dependent on any counter names, particularly those that start with prefixes other than "java.".

Additional warning: all source code links below point to the specific [hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u60](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u60) branch and the specific file revisions. The links themselves should work *forever*, but as the JVM evolves the new file versions can make information in this post obsolete.

The first source of information is the `jstat` documentation ([jstat 8 unix docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jstat.html), [jstat 8 windows docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jstat.html), [jstat 7 docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstat.html)). It provides a human-readable albeit short description for a lot of performance counters, for example:

```
FGC: Number of full GC events.
```

The second source of information is the `jstat` source code ([jstat source code, jdk7u60 branch](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u60/jdk/file/33c1eee28403/src/share/classes/sun/tools/jstat)) and specifically its resource files: [jstat_options](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u60/jdk/file/33c1eee28403/src/share/classes/sun/tools/jstat/resources/jstat_options) and [jstat_unsupported_options](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u60/jdk/file/33c1eee28403/src/share/classes/sun/tools/jstat/resources/jstat_unsupported_options). For example, searching for `FGC` in `jstat_options` results in the following snippet:

```
column {
  header "^FGC^"    /* Full Collections */
  data sun.gc.collector.1.invocations
  align center
  width 5
  scale raw
  format "0"
}
```

Using `jstat_options` source code and `jstat` documentation it is possible to map most of internal counter names with prefixes `sun.gc.collector` and `sun.gc.generation` to human-readable descriptions or at least get some additional information from the comments inside `jstat_options` file.

Most of the counters with `sun.gc.policy` prefix are defined in [gcPolicyCounters.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u60/hotspot/file/ba66650acf63/src/share/vm/gc_implementation/shared/gcPolicyCounters.cpp) and [gcAdaptivePolicyCounters.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u60/hotspot/file/ba66650acf63/src/share/vm/gc_implementation/shared/gcAdaptivePolicyCounters.cpp) and also in the GC-specific implementations (look for `somethingCounters.cpp` files in GC-specific folders located on the same level as shared folder) but i was not able to find human-readable descriptions for them.

I was not able to find where counters with `sun.gc.tlab` prefix are defined. Checking-out the full JDK source code and grepping it for relevant counter names should do the trick for those inclined to find everything.

Comment: I suspect that `tlab` stands for Thread Local Allocation Buffer (https://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/the-real-thing)